# reduce namespace pollution in python scripts

Tags: python, legacy

I am working on some old python code and I was wondering if there is an easy way to find out which modules are imported but never used. I have a few hundred python scripts, each importing tens of modules (most scripts where copy-pasted by some template).

Comment: This is normally the job of a *linter* tool. [Flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8/) would certainly deserve a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) can do this. It reports "[Unused import <module>](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html#variables-checker-messages)" (warning named `unused-import`, code W0611).

This warning is enabled by default along with many others, but if you want to check for this warning specifically, you can do:

```
pylint --disable=all --enable=unused-import *.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) does inform you if any modules or variables are used or not. That would be good for you in my opinion as an IDE.